Local file path to File/Blob to be read by SheetJS's read function
I want to use SheetJS to display an Excel sheet in a small app I am working on. Currently, the Excel workbook is on my local machine, and I want to read the file using SheetJS, then use SheetJS's sheet_to_html functionality to display the sheet in the browser.
SheetJS provides a readFile function, but this does not work on the browser side. They offer a read file too, which accepts a binary blob of data. I am pretty new to Javascript, and can't seem to get my local file path as a string into the correct format to be read by SheetJS read.
Here's what I want:
const file = "my_local_excel_file.xlsx";
const reader = new FileReader();
data = // ... read file into a binary array buffer from reader
wb = XLSX.read(data);
// get sheet, display as HTML

I've been through all the documentation and previous StackOverflow questions, but I can't seem to find an answer to this question. Nearly all other examples have some File type which is already a Blob to be read by XLSX.read, such as from an upload button. However, my file is coming directly as a string.
I do have a Python backend, and I have tried to parse the data using pandas and passing the data as JSON to SheetJS, but while that displays something in the browser, the formatting is all wrong.
Does anyone have any advice?

Evidently you need to readFile on the server side (I guess a workbook is on the server) and provide the resulting html to get read by the client browser.

Do you really need to read a file from the client's file system from in-browser JavaScript?  Or are you able to modify that use case?  If the file exists on the server then it will be much easier to read it without user interaction.  If the file must be client-side then you'll probably need to add a file input to the page and have the user provide the file.

@rotabor My backend is Python. I was reading the file in using Python and converting it to a HTML table, but now I want to try to use SheetJS.

@David I can load the file using Python in the backend first, if that's what you mean? Like I said, I tried passing this as JSON to the client-side and getting SheetJS to read it, but this currently is not formatting the data correctly. Maybe I need to continue down this path, however.

@user_15: "I can load the file using Python in the backend first, if that's what you mean?" - Does this mean that the file is on the server instead of on the client?  This is a very significant detail, you're going to want to clearly make this decision before implementing anything.  In your web application, when you need data from this file, where does this file exist?  On the server or on the client?  (Even if the two are the same overall computer, if they weren't then where would the file exist?)

For security reasons the browser cannot directly access the local filesystem via code. The FileReader API you are trying to use relies on a <input type="file"> to access local files

@David It's a bit complex. This app sits within some existing, mostly Python-based, software. A function of that software calls the app, grabs a file from a client-provided file path, which might be a local file on their side or a path to a file stored in the cloud, and then processes it and shows it in the browser. In either case, the file is client-side. Even if it wasn't, I expected there to be a way of pulling a file from the server and passing it to SheetJS read in the correct format a bit more easily. Maybe that's my naivety.

@user_15: "In either case, the file is client-side." - Browsers can't read the client's file system without user interaction.  (Imagine how dangerous the internet would be if any website could read the files on your computer without asking.)  Users supply files using a <input type="file"> and the HTML file API works from that.  If in your scenario the user needs to supply the file then you're simply missing the step where the user supplies the file.

@user_15: If the file were to exist server-side then you could make a simple AJAX request to read it, which wouldn't require user interaction.  Given the overall scenario, if that's an option then it's probably an easier one.  But as long as the file needs to be client-side then the user would need to provide it to the page.  (And, no, server-side code, Python or otherwise, would not be able to read a client-side file.)

@David Thanks. On making a simple Ajax request to read it, I think this is still where I am misunderstanding. How do I get the Excel file data into a format on the server side that SheetJS can read? I can load the data on the server side in Python, then I need to build a HTML page that displays the data using SheetJS. From what I've seen, Ajax can't help me here.

@user_15: If the file can live server-side then any server-side code can read it from the server's file system.  The server-side code could provide an API endpoint to return the raw file data to the client.  Server-side code isn't even technically necessary of course, if the file is openly available on the web server then an AJAX request can just download it directly.  Once fetched from the server, the client can do whatever it likes with that data.  Which includes feeding it into this SheetJS library.
